# Separate results on the fly with Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, mongoid

I have a collection of Items, in which I have "books" and "videos":

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5461c8f4426f727f16ba0600"),
    "name" : "Pursuit of Happiness",
    "dst" : "video",
    "detail" : {
        "director" : [ 
            "Mahmoud Chavoushi"
        ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5461c8f4426f727f16ba0600"),
    "name" : "Bee",
    "dst" : "book",
    "detail" : {
        "author" : [ 
            "Mahmoud Chavoushi"
        ]
}
```

I would like to make a Search query so that I get separated results on the same query:

- Books: Query for "name" field of items where `dst: "book"`.
- Videos: Query for "name" field of items where `dst: "video"`.

Is this possible?

I'm using [searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Elasticsearch's [Multi-Search API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html). That way you can fire two separate queries in a single request.